# Why did "Melquiades" lie to his friend?

Tags: plot-explanation, three-burials-of-melquiades-estrada

In *The Three Burials of Melquiades Estrada*, why did "Melquiades" lie to his friend about having a wife and kids in an imaginary village called "Himenez"?